# Is it possible to use HTML, CSS, and Javascript to create Iphone apps that can access Iphone bluetooth pairing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

Can I create a web based language (HTML CSS and Javascript) iphone app that can pair to other phones using bluetooth and send information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the built in browser using a purely web based app as the browser wouldn't allow you to transfer files. You would need to develop an IOS app using the native IOS language, or if you want to stick with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, you can consider using a framework like [Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/).

Comment: Could I embed code within my web code, similar to a Java applet, but in this case native IOS code?

Comment: Nope, IOS and the native Safari browser don't allow you to do that, you would need to develop a custom app for that.